# JUnit - Exception In Initializer Error

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to test a class with a static methods and I'm having an error in this line:

```
FormReferenceDataPopulator target = new FormReferenceDataPopulator();
```

and here's the failure trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at au.necdl.pexa.web.document.form.FormReferenceDataPopulatorTest.<init>(FormReferenceDataPopulatorTest.java:15)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate bean of class [au.necdl.pexa.service.address.CountryService]
  at au.necdl.pexa.core.PexaContextAware.getBean(PexaContextAware.java:65)
  at au.necdl.pexa.web.document.form.FormReferenceDataPopulator.<clinit>(FormReferenceDataPopulator.java:29)    ... 23 more
```

Comment: The relevant part of your stacktrace: *Could not locate bean of class [au.necdl.pexa.service.address.CountryService]*

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of clues in the stack trace that point where the error is

a) ExceptionIninitializerError --> FormReferenceDataPopulatorTest.
This indicates that the error happened during the construction of this object. The ExceptionIninitializerError specifically point to the fact that the exception occurred during static initialization block or variable

**ExceptionIninitializerError**
An ExceptionIninitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

b) Like Robby has pointed out in his comment `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate bean of class [au.necdl.pexa.service.address.CountryService]` shows where the error exact is.